# Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))' firewall INetFwPolicy2

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Access is denied.

```
        private  void MakeRule(string IP, int Protocole, NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_ ruleDirection, string ruleName)
        {
            Type tNetFwPolicy2 = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");
            INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(tNetFwPolicy2);
            var currentProfiles = fwPolicy2.CurrentProfileTypes;

            

            // Let's create a new rule
            INetFwRule2 Rule = (INetFwRule2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));
            Rule.Enabled = true;
            

            NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_ direction = ruleDirection;
            Rule.Direction = direction; //Inbound
            Rule.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_BLOCK;
            Rule.Profiles = currentProfiles;

            Rule.Protocol = protNumber; // ANY/TCP/UDP

            try
            {
                Rule.RemoteAddresses = str;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't add Rules. Maybe a Format failure?");
            }

            //Rule.LocalPorts = "81"; //Port 81

            //Name of rule
            Rule.Name = ruleName;
            
            // ...//
            //Rule.Profiles = (int)NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE_.NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE_MAX;

            // Now add the rule
            INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
            try
            {
                firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(Rule);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Are you running from VS?  VS does not automatically run As Admin.   You need to right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin to have admin privilege.

Comment: I am Using Visual Studio and i have the credential of the admin. By using these credential can I add rule in firewall. I am using impersonation but how to force this specific code to run as admin not the complete application?

Comment: When I open my solution as an administrator the code work perfectly but i dont want to dos this

Comment: The only way I know is to built a separate application for just the code and the set the exe with Run as Admin.  You need to create a process to change privilege level and that has to be set at System Level and not from a lower level process.

Comment: Good Idea will Try this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testabc user have the administrator right.

```
        //Run EXTERNAL APP AS AN ADMIN

        var pass = new SecureString();
         pass.AppendChar('t');
         pass.AppendChar('e');
         pass.AppendChar('s');
         pass.AppendChar('t');
         

        var ps1File = @"C:\Users\testabc\Desktop\LT_Admin.ps1";
        ProcessStartInfo processAdmin;
        processAdmin = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processAdmin.UseShellExecute = false;
        processAdmin.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processAdmin.WindowStyle=System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        processAdmin.Password = pass;
        processAdmin.UserName = "testabc";
        processAdmin.Domain = "soft";
        processAdmin.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
        processAdmin.Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file \"{ps1File}\"";
        processAdmin.RedirectStandardOutput = true;           
        Process.Start(processAdmin);
```

In ps1File  I have this code

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -Verb RunAs

Working perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your app run as administrator, you can create a manifest file to make it work.

First, please right click your project and add a new item called `Application Manifest File`.

Second, please find `requestedExecutionLevel` tag and change into the following tag:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Third, you will get a UAC prompt when they start the program. Choose Restart under different credentials.

Finally, you can run the program with the amdin power.

Also, you can read the following link to use c# code to run the app as admin.

[Run as administrator C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/db6647a3-85ca-4dc4-b661-fbbd36bd561f/run-as-administrator-c?forum=winforms)

Comment: This is not Solution of my problem with this the user have to give the admin credential but my admin credential come from web API. User don't know the administration credential of the system.